# Error with pivot_wider across reader to compare timepoint responses

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where we have derived responses (`FINAL_RESP`) at various timepoints across 2 different readers (`READER`) for each subject (`SUBJ_ID`). I want to compare the output and want to `pivot_wider` but my brain is struggling at the moment.

My current dataset (first 2 subjects):

```
> print.data.frame(TIMEPOINT_COMP)
       SUBJ_ID READER FINAL_RESP reader
1   1001-31169      1   BASELINE      1
2   1001-31169      1         SD      1
3   1001-31169      1         SD      1
4   1001-31169      1         SD      1
5   1001-31169      1        PDu      1
6   1001-31169      1         SD      1
7   1001-31169      1         SD      1
8   1001-31169      1         SD      1
9   1001-31169      1         PR      1
10  1001-31169      1         PR      1
11  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
12  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
13  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
14  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
15  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
16  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
17  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
18  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
19  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
20  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
21  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
22  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
23  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
24  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
25  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
26  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
27  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
28  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
29  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
30  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
31  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
32  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
33  1001-31169      1        PDc      1
34  1001-31169      4   BASELINE      2
35  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
36  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
37  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
38  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
39  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
40  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
41  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
42  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
43  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
44  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
45  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
46  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
47  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
48  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
49  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
50  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
51  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
52  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
53  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
54  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
55  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
56  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
57  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
58  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
59  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
60  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
61  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
62  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
63  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
64  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
65  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
66  1001-31169      4        PDc      2
67  1002-31169      2   BASELINE      1
68  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
69  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
70  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
71  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
72  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
73  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
74  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
75  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
76  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
77  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
78  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
79  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
80  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
81  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
82  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
83  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
84  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
85  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
86  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
87  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
88  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
89  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
90  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
91  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
92  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
93  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
94  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
95  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
96  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
97  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
98  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
99  1002-31169      2        PDc      1
100 1002-31169      2        PDc      1
101 1002-31169      2        PDc      1
102 1002-31169      2        PDc      1
103 1002-31169      2        PDc      1
104 1002-31169      2        PDc      1
105 1002-31169      2        PDc      1
106 1002-31169      2        PDc      1
107 1002-31169      2        PDc      1
108 1002-31169      4   BASELINE      2
109 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
110 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
111 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
112 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
113 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
114 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
115 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
116 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
117 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
118 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
119 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
120 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
121 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
122 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
123 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
124 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
125 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
126 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
127 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
128 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
129 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
130 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
131 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
132 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
133 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
134 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
135 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
136 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
137 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
138 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
139 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
140 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
141 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
142 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
143 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
144 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
145 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
146 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
147 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
148 1002-31169      4        PDc      2
```

Here is my current code:

```
TIMEPOINT_COMP <- RESP %>% select(SUBJ_ID, READER, FINAL_RESP) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(SUBJ_ID) %>% 
  mutate(reader = rleid(READER)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="reader", values_from="FINAL_RESP", names_prefix="READER")
```

Which outputs the following:

```
> head(TIMEPOINT_COMP, 15)
# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   SUBJ_ID [10]
   SUBJ_ID    READER READER1    READER2   
   <chr>      <fct>  <list>     <list>    
 1 1001-31169 1      <chr [33]> <NULL>    
 2 1001-31169 4      <NULL>     <chr [33]>
 3 1002-31169 2      <chr [41]> <NULL>    
 4 1002-31169 4      <NULL>     <chr [41]>
 5 1003-31169 4      <chr [6]>  <NULL>    
 6 1003-31169 5      <NULL>     <chr [6]> 
 7 1004-31169 1      <chr [4]>  <NULL>    
 8 1004-31169 3      <NULL>     <chr [4]> 
 9 1005-31169 1      <chr [9]>  <NULL>    
10 1005-31169 4      <NULL>     <chr [9]> 
11 1007-31169 1      <chr [5]>  <NULL>    
12 1007-31169 3      <NULL>     <chr [5]> 
13 1008-31169 1      <chr [6]>  <NULL>    
14 1008-31169 3      <NULL>     <chr [6]> 
15 1010-31169 3      <chr [12]> <NULL>
```

What the heck am I doing wrong? Apologies if it is a silly error as it's been a long week.

**Edit 1**: Here is what the desired output should look like:

```
> example
      SUBJ_ID  READER1  READER2
1  1001-31169 BASELINE BASELINE
2  1001-31169       SD      PDc
3  1001-31169       SD      PDc
4  1001-31169       SD      PDc
5  1001-31169      PDu      PDc
6  1001-31169       SD      PDc
7  1001-31169       SD      PDc
8  1001-31169       SD      PDc
9  1001-31169       PR      PDc
10 1001-31169       PR      PDc
```

Reprex (first 2 subjects):

```
TIMEPOINT_COMP = structure(list(SUBJ_ID = c("1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", 
"1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1001-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169"
), READER = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), FINAL_RESP = c("BASELINE", 
"SD", "SD", "SD", "PDu", "SD", "SD", "SD", "PR", "PR", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "BASELINE", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "BASELINE", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "BASELINE", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
"PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc"), reader = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-148L), groups = structure(list(SUBJ_ID = c("1001-31169", "1002-31169"
), .rows = structure(list(1:66, 67:148), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of what you want the final output to look like? Also, is `rleid` from `data.table`?

Comment: @eipi10 added an example of what the desired output should look like. And, yes, `rleid` is from the `data.table` package. I typically prefer to work in `dplyr`, but I really like the `rleid` function and tend to use it for grouped IDs. Here is the function documentation, if you are interested: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/rleid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
TIMEPOINT_COMP_UNIQUE <- TIMEPOINT_COMP %>% select(SUBJ_ID, READER, FINAL_RESP) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(SUBJ_ID) %>% 
  mutate(reader = rleid(READER)) 
TIMEPOINT_COMP_UNIQUE 

READER1 <- TIMEPOINT_COMP_UNIQUE %>% filter(reader == 1) %>% select(SUBJ_ID, FINAL_RESP) %>% rename(READER1 = FINAL_RESP) %>% ungroup()
READER2 <- TIMEPOINT_COMP_UNIQUE %>% filter(reader == 2) %>% select(SUBJ_ID, FINAL_RESP) %>% rename(READER2 = FINAL_RESP) %>% ungroup() %>% pull(READER2)
TIMEPOINT_COMP_ALL <- cbind.data.frame(READER1, READER2) %>% mutate(MATCH = if_else(READER1 == READER2, 1, 0))
TIMEPOINT_COMP_ALL
```

Output:

```
      SUBJ_ID  READER1  READER2 MATCH
1  1001-31169 BASELINE BASELINE     1
2  1001-31169       SD      PDc     0
3  1001-31169       SD      PDc     0
4  1001-31169       SD      PDc     0
5  1001-31169      PDu      PDc     0
6  1001-31169       SD      PDc     0
7  1001-31169       SD      PDc     0
8  1001-31169       SD      PDc     0
9  1001-31169       PR      PDc     0
10 1001-31169       PR      PDc     0
```